Core memory output line question
How is a bit read from the core memory pictured below? I understand current through 1 and 1 vs 0 and 0 will change the torus magnets field setting a bit. I’m confused how this field is read back using select and output line. How does the field impact the output line?

Ref website
More specifically Can you explain the sequence of setting and reading in terms of current applied to the 1 and 0 wires? I’m suspecting 1 and 1 both have same current direction to set the bit. When a VM is connected to sense it will get a pulse. Then this is used to set 1 and 1 again. I’m confused about reversing the current on both 1 and 1 and what that does to the bit. Also in general when connecting VM to sense what is happening with the magnetic field causing a current pulse

Start with this YouTube video -- lesson 1. And then, if you care, buy some cores and a board from him. He's gold on the topic. You will have to contact him via here to get some. They aren't listed as available. But if you contact him directly, he will sell some to you. You can also get old core memories off of ebay and elsewhere. It's worth the time to play. These are square loop ferrites but not necessarily the kind found in magamps. Yes, I play with these. Yes I bought from him. He has a book, too. Buy it.

If you still have questions after you watch the videos then I'll try and answer. But not before. Too much good stuff is already there for the taking. I won't waste time you can find there in clear, concise, detailed, and well-presented videos.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AwsInQLmjXc  This video was helpful. Can you explain what is going on with the magnetic field in the core and the sense line when voltage is applied to flip the field? How does the produce the pulse? Also a little mysterious to me is the inhibit line which was added do you know how the functions?

He explains this. There's a rapid change of flux that takes place. This causes a sudden pulse in the sense line. The inhibit line counters the sum of the x and y lines. All this is explained pretty well in the videos. The book isn't necessarily better. So getting the book isn't strictly necessary. If you are not following the videos, you may not be helped much by the book. I recommend you buy some cores from him and then just personally perform the experiments and see for yourself. Note also that you do need to understand some basics. He assumes something from you.

Thank you @notaorb for editing your question and making it better.


How is a bit read from the core memory pictured below?


Consider reading core memory is done by erasing core memory.
As there is only 1 sense wire (output) only 1 magnetic core can be erased at a time.
If the sense wire produces little or no current, then the magnetic core was already erased. Consider the bit represented by this magnetic core as being not set.
If the sense wire produces a significant amount of current, then the magnetic core underwent magnetic reversal. Consider the bit represented by this magnetic core as being set.
To preserve core memory data, any magnetic core found to be set will need to be written to again to return it to the set state.


...[how is] setting and reading [done] in terms of current applied to the ... wires ...?


A certain amount of current passing through a magnetic core can cause a magnetic reversal event.
Only half the necessary current is passed through the column wire and the other half through the row wire.
Only the magnetic core where the column and row wire intersect will experience enough total current to cause the magnetic core to undergo a magnetic reversal.
Current in both wires need to flow through the magnetic core of interest in the same direction to set the core.
To clear the core, the current in both wires need to flow in the opposite direction.


Can you explain the sequence of setting and reading in terms of current applied to the 1 and  0 wires? I’m suspecting 1 and 1 both have same current direction to set the bit. When a VM is connected to sense it will get a pulse. Then this is used to set 1 and 1 again. I’m confused about reversing the current on both 1 and 1 and what that does to the bit. Also in general when connecting VM to sense what is happening with the magnetic field causing a current pulse.

I can add to the answer.  But you need to add these specific questions your question above.  The point of the many stackexchange websites are to have curated questions and concise answer for any in the future with the same question.
